# How to create a feature collection after importing different shapefiles from assets in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am importing 2 different shapefiles from assets to plot the time series chart of MODIS

[image: imported assets]

but I am unable to make the feature collection out of these shapefiles

how to do that?

```
var Haryana_state = ee.FeatureCollection('users/abhilashaanu92/HaryanaBoundary');

Map.addLayer(Haryana_state);

var Punjab_state = ee.FeatureCollection('users/abhilashaanu92/punjab_state_boundary');

Map.addLayer(Punjab_state);

// Combine features into a feature collection.
var both_states = ee.FeatureCollection([Haryana_state, Punjab_state]).flatten();

Map.addLayer(both_states);

// Load MODIS vegetation indices data and subset annual images.


var vegIndices = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')
                     .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01'))
                     .select(['NDVI', 'EVI']);

// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .seriesByRegion({
          imageCollection: vegIndices,
          band: 'NDVI',
          regions: both_states,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 500,
          seriesProperty: 'label',
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average NDVI Value by Date',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'NDVI (x1e4)',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['f0af07', '0f8755', '76b349'],
        });
print(chart);
```

if I put the name of a single shapefile variable in the regions then it is working but when I combine the 2 shapefiles into a feature collection then it is showing the error.

How to rectify this?

I want output something like this. (the time series of both the states on the same chart).

[image: different region time series on same chart]

[Chart Source URL](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_image_collection#uichartimageseriesbyregion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things need to be done here. First, add `.flatten()` after combining the two FeatureCollections.

This way, you make a collection of features (FeatureCollection), which is desired.
Otherwise, you end up with a collection of FeatureCollections, which prompts the error.

Second, the `seriesProperty` needs to match the label of your FeatureCollection. In this case, 'STATE_NAME'. You can check this by adding print(both_states) to check how your new FeatureCollection looks like. I've updated the code.

```
var Haryana_state = ee.FeatureCollection('users/abhilashaanu92/HaryanaBoundary');

Map.addLayer(Haryana_state);

var Punjab_state = ee.FeatureCollection('users/abhilashaanu92/punjab_state_boundary');

Map.addLayer(Punjab_state);

// Combine features into a feature collection.
var both_states = ee.FeatureCollection([Haryana_state, Punjab_state]).flatten();
print('Check the properties; this will tell you what seriesProperty to use', both_states)

Map.addLayer(both_states);

// Load MODIS vegetation indices data and subset annual images.


var vegIndices = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')
                     .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01'))
                     .select(['NDVI', 'EVI']);

// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .seriesByRegion({
          imageCollection: vegIndices,
          band: 'NDVI',
          regions: both_states,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 500,
          seriesProperty: 'STATE_NAME',
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average NDVI Value by Date',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'NDVI (x1e4)',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['f0af07', '0f8755', '76b349'],
        });
print(chart);
```

Comment: Can you please edit it in the code above ? I’ve tried, not getting it the right way

Comment: Hey @CrossLord, I am unable to see the edit that you made in the code.

Comment: The code joined both features but plotting the data of only one polygon (Punjab only).

Comment: First of all, you haven't shared your Assets so it's difficult to duplicate your code. To answer your previous comment, using the seriesProperty: 'system:index', instead of 'label' should do the trick.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/abhilashaanu92/HaryanaBoundary

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/abhilashaanu92/punjab_state_boundary

Comment: You can access the assets from these URL's

Comment: these are 2 different polygons, and I want the time series of NDVI on the same chart.

Comment: Come on man, I'm trying to help you out here. Can you please make your Assets publicly available? Go to the Assets tab, click on the Asset, click Share and then check 'anyone can read'

Comment: So Sorry @CrossLord, I am new to GEE, so didn't knew about that. I have shared it now.

Comment: Updated the initial answer.

Comment: Which initial answer ?

Comment: The only answer there is.

Comment: Thanks a ton brother, it worked as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `ee.FeatureColleciton.merge()` method. In your case it will be like below:

```
var Haryana_state = ee.FeatureCollection('users/abhilashaanu92/HaryanaBoundary');

Map.addLayer(Haryana_state);

var Punjab_state = ee.FeatureCollection('users/abhilashaanu92/punjab_state_boundary');

Map.addLayer(Punjab_state);

// Combine features into a feature collection.
var both_states = Haryana_state.merge(Punjab_state)

Map.addLayer(both_states);
```